# Intent filter для интентов с именем пакета

Tags: android, android-intent

Добрый день. 
Можно ли сделать интент фильтр, который бы проверял название пакета в интенте?

Ситуация такая: у приложения есть 3 антивити для шаринга, пользователь в нативном селекторе сам выбирает куда ему шарить. И есть клавиатура bitmojii, которая отправляет картинку в виде интента.

Но из-за того, что активитей у нас 3 - вылазит селектор при выборе картинки с клавиатуры.

Интент отличается только тем, что у него в названии пакета стоит наше приложение.

Как можно в этом случае обойтись без селектора, но оставить 3 варианта в простом шаринге?